# XCode Command-T-style autocomplete for zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I've just started using the Command-T plugin for vim, and it rocks. In case you haven't heard of it, it allows you to type something like this:

```
Sb
```

to select Something.hs-boot from the list

```
src/project/Control/Whatever/Foobs.hs
src/project/Control/Whatever/Something.hs-boot
src/project/Control/Whatever/Something.hs
```

And so on.

I was wondering if I could use a similar autocompletion style with zsh. I understand that the shell completion couldn't be nearly as extensive as the vim completion because the shell complition probably shouldn't be searching the entire system every time you type a letter, but is there some sort of similar completion where I could at least type

```
s/p/c/w/Sb<tab>
```

and get an effect similar to the one above?

I've heard that zsh has a pretty well-programmable autocomplete functionality, but my shell-fu is fairly weak.

Anybody know how to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete partial paths, it's enough to just init the completion system (at least on my system, using `zsh v4.3.17`):

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
zmodload zsh/complist
```

If you want to get a little more fancy, you can make the matching case-insensitive:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'
```

**Update 1:**

I don't know if you can do Command-T-style autocompletion ... but as zsh has to get **all** matches before it displays something, doing this on-the-fly, especially somewhere that has a lot of subdirectories/files, might not be feasible.

You could however use:

```
**/*thing <Tab>
```

The `**` matches all files & subdirectories of the current directory.

**Idea:**  If it does not have to be an up-to-date list of files, you could potentially write a completion function that uses the output of `locate` (i.e. a pre-computed file list)

**Update 2:**
https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#fuzzy-completion-for-bash-and-zsh

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting alternative is to use something like [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd).

Comment: I second the recommendation for fasd. With fasd, you could simply type `v Sb` and it would open the file matching 'Sb' best in vim, according to time elapsed and frequency of edits of that file.